# I can not get my DVD's to work. Crashing VLC player

Tags: 14.04, vlc, dvd

I can not get my DVDs to work in vlc or any other player. How do I fix this?
I have tried to install vlc gremlin and other players.

Comment: Open up a terminal and install the necessary codecs using `sudo apt-get install libdvdcss libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 ubuntu-restricted-extras` then try playing again in VLC.

Answer (score 3):

You need the library `libdvdcss`. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libdvdcss).

The package `libdvdcss2` is not included in the official repositories, but can be easily installed.

Two short commands should help.

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
sudo sh /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

Comment: Thank you all very much the problem has been resolved you all rock

Comment: And where is my green flag? :\

Comment: @XAQZOAR You've marked [that other answer about damaged DVDs](https://askubuntu.com/a/609506/22949) as the accepted answer, even though your comment indicating the problem was resolved is here on *this* answer. Did it turn out that your DVDs were physically damaged (and did not, for example, play on another computer known to play DVDs well, an embedded set-top DVD player, etc.)? Or did you mean to mark *this* answer as accepted?

Comment: @EliahKagan Thanks for the support, but you should comment on his question and not mine. :)

Comment: @XAQZOAR Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)